# Create new dataframe that flattens out list column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  list
1   [543,4]
2   [1,2]
3   [3,4]
4   [7,8]
5   [9,10,11]
```

Where ID is an int and 'list' is a column that has a list in each value.  What would be an efficient way of creating another dataframe from this one where the list is flattened into a column where each row is a value in the list repeating the ID value for the length of each list.

The following is the desired output:

```
ID  Value
1   543
1   4
2   1
2   2
3   3
3   4
4   7
4   8
5   9
5   10
5   11
```

One limitation, my company is still using Python 2.7 unfortunately....

Comment: for Pandas 0.25+, you can do `df.explode('list')`.

Comment: Still riding with pandas pandas-0.24.2